# How do I properly annotate two JPA entities which are in a parent child relationship?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, entity-relationship, one-to-many

Maybe this is a question with an easy answer ... but I don't get it running. At persist() I get the exception that the referential key in the child table is null (which of course is not allowed by the database). I have a recipe and some steps for preparation.

I'm using EclipseLink 2.4.1

Recipe.java (rcpid is autoset by JPA)

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    long rcpid;

    List<Recipestep> recipesteps = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy="recipe",
        targetEntity=Recipestep.class )
// This does NOT work. Following line tries to access a join-table !!!
// @JoinColumn(name="rcpid", referencedColumnName="rcpid") 
        public List<Recipestep> getRecipesteps() { return recipesteps; }
    // some more attributes, getters and setters
}
```

Recipestep.java (rpsid is autoset by JPA)

```
@Entity
public class Recipestep {
    @Id
    long rpsid;

    Recipe recipe;

    @ManyToOne( targetEntity=Recipe.class )
    @JoinColumn( name="rcpid" )
    public Recipe getRecipe() { return recipe; }

    // some more attributes, getters and setters
}
```

The code above is a valid workaround. However to have clean (and supportable) code, the relationship should be only one-way with a collection in the parent which references all its children.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not referencing the Recipe proper in the Recipestep instead of having a long field?

Comment: Of course. There is no reason (except an EclipseLink bug) to have a back reference from the child to its parent. Instead I consider this as bad programming since you could easily and up in circular references (causing stack overflows) or flowing orphans (causing data garbage). To have JPA know about the column to use I just put it there.

Comment: If you want to have a bidirectional relation that can be cascaded or where you want to be able to traverse 'upwards' without refetching the parent, JPA offers no other way but to have a reference to the proper entity, so you would have to use the `Recipe` reference, other considerations aside. This does not apply to unidirectional relations, but you do seem to have a bidirectional one. As to the error - the column "recipebo_rcpid" is in fact unknown to JPA. Please see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped this as a unidirectional one to many, but have two mappings for the recipestep rcpid database column.  Try changing the long rcpid to

```
@ManyTOne
Recipe rcp;
```

And then remove the joincolumn definition from the oneToMany and make it bidirectional by marking it as mappedby the rcp manyToOne relation.  An example is posted here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany

Eclipselink will always insert nulls on unidirectional oneToMany relations using a joincolumn when first inserting the target entity, and then update it later when it processes the Recipe entity.  Your rcpid mapping in Recipestep is also likely null, which means you have two write able mappings for the same field which is bad especially when they conflict like this.

Comment: First of all thanks for the ideas. I modified my classes accordingly and now get the error as written above.

I would expect to set this in proper programming as an unidirectional @OneToMany link. This is not supported by EclipseLink. I found a half year old bug there 391279.

Comment: You set a manytoone and onetomany, but they are both separate independant mappings.  The onetomany is missing the mappedby identifier that tells it about the manytoone, and it looks like your manytoone didn't define a joincolumn annotation and so is defaulting to recipebo_id

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for your support in finding a workaround. Do you know which JPA implementation is correctly supporting unidirectional relationships?

Comment: I don't know how other providers might work, as I develop EclipseLink.  Other options though might be to delay constraint processing until the end of the transaction, allowing the foreign key to have its value set.  Don't forget to vote for the EclipseLink bug to have it resolved, and if you pay for Oracle support, that is another way to push to have the functionality added.

Comment: Why is it required to wait until the end of the transaction?
I would implement this straight-forward:
1. if primary key of recipe == null => create it
2. Insert parent (recipe in this case)
3. Loop through all collections in recipe. Set child reference to parent to parents primary key. Then do the same with the children in the collections.
:-)

Comment: My understanding of the problem was that there is a not-null constraint on rcpid in Recipestep and you wanted to use the undirectional OneToMany for the field.  Delaying constraint processing would allow EclipseLink to insert null to the field and then update it later.  Because the constraint is checked at the end, it isn't violated, so you can use the unidirectional mapping in this way.  Changing EclipseLink to support your usecase might not be so simple, but if you are willing to try, please submit patches through the bug.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30011/discussion-between-hajo-and-chris)

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the default JPA behaviour. Adding an entity to the `recipesteps` list is not sufficient to create a bidirectional relation.

To solve the issue you need to set the `rcpid` explicitly on every element in the list.

**EDIT**: I think the issue is that JPA does not know where to store the id of the `Recipe` in the Recipestep table. It assumes a name ("recipebo_rcpid"), but your table seems to lack it.

Try adding the column "recipe_id" to the `Recipestep` table and a `mappedBy` attribute to the `@OneToMany` annotation:

```
@OneToMany(
  cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
  fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
  mappedBy = "recipe" )
```

You probably do not need the `targetEntity` attribute in the annotation- the `List` is typed already.

Comment: Nice idea. But does not work since recipe.rcpid is set automatically by EclipseLink. I don't know it beforehand.

Comment: Thanks Kostja for your ideas. I didn't properly state from the beginning on that I definitely wanted to have a uni-directional @OneToMany relationship. I still do not understand why I need a back-reference instead of just the rcpid?

Comment: @Hajo - you're welcome, although I'm afraid I didnt help :) What I mean is - You need a proper reference for a bidirectional relation if you want to navigate from a child to a parent and want to avoid refetching the parent entity from the DB for each step (performance and code complexity). It does not apply to unidiectional relations.

Comment: Hi Kostja. You were absolutely correct in your suggestion, since my approach is not correctly supported at least by EclipseLink :-(
Examples like this one (recipe with steps) or (invoice with lines) are very clear structures which require a collection of the children in the parent but no child is living by itself. So it does not need to have a reference to its parent.